# portlet:renderUrl - how to make URL relative?

Tags: https, portlet, relative-path, taglib

I have problem with http vs https link in portlets. I work with jboss liferay 6.0 but it is not relevant in this case.

Portlets may be used in http or https mode. Portlet tag creates absolute URL. I would need this relative to work correctly with http vs https.

I know secure attribute, but I don't want it always secure.

```
<portlet:renderURL var="detailLink">
    <portlet:param name="id" value="${recordId}" />
    <portlet:param name="backURL" value="${backLink}" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

Please no javascript for this.

Thank you

Comment: Couldn't you just manipulate *detailLink* manually?

Comment: I use this tag in many portlets. Should I create my own tag for something what must be already solved - or am I really only one with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: In a single site the same portlet should have some URLs `http` and some `https`, is this what you want?

Comment: No, when I hit web page `http://whatever.com` I want to see links on this page `http://whatever.com/nextPage`. But when I hit the web page `https://whatever.com` I want to see links on this page `https://whatever.com/nextPage`

Answer (score 0):

On the server, you will know whether you are in http or http mode. So you could create it server side using something like this

```
PortletUrl detailLink renderResponse.createRenderUrl();
detailLink.setSecure(renderRequest.isSecure());

//set all the params on detailLink here

model.setAttribute("detailLink",detailLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Relative URL** concept here...

If you don't want to go ahead with javascript then you can create a Java method in your jsp page, preferably in a common jsp page like init.jsp and place the following method:

```
<%!

private String _getRelativePath(String cURL) {
        if (Validator.isNull(cURL)) {
            return cURL;
        }

        if (cURL.startsWith(Http.HTTP)) {
            int pos = cURL.indexOf(
                StringPool.SLASH, Http.HTTPS_WITH_SLASH.length());

            cURL = cURL.substring(pos);
        }

        return cURL;
}

%>
```

You can call this method on your url and it would return the string having path and parameters.

For example; if you pass cURL as

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home?p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=pop_up&p_p_mode=view&_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Flogin
```

then it will return

```
/web/guest/home?p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=pop_up&p_p_mode=view&_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Flogin
```

Also you can use **themeDisplay.getURLPortal()** method to split absolute url to get required relative url out of it.

```
<%!

private String _getRelativePath(String cURL, ThemeDisplay themeDisplay) {

        if (Validator.isNull(cURL)) {
            return cURL;
        }

        String [] urlArr = cURL.split(themeDisplay.getURLPortal());

        return urlArr[1];
}

%>
```

This mechanism will fulfill your requirement.